# Does WP_PROXY_HOST support https/socks5 proxies?

Tags: wordpress, proxy

Trying to set up a proxy in wp-config.php according to

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_proxy/

But does it support https/socks5 or just HTTP ones?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to this page it does

https://engineering.hmn.md/guides/dev-env/proxying/#b-using-ssh-tunnels